# Why curl command of elasticsearch is not working in Ubuntu?

Tags: elastic-stack, ubuntu-18.04

When I write this query in kibana console, it shows me correct output.
I copy the curl command from kibana then run it in Ubuntu terminal but nothing works.

I am using this curl command

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/_sql?format=json" -H 'Content- 
Type: application/json' -d'{ "query": "select * from abusix_1 where 
Date between \"2019-07-29T08:00:45.000Z\" and \"2019-08- 
29T08:00:45.000Z\""}'
```

and it shows me this output

```
{"error":{"root_cause": 
[{"type":"verification_exception","reason":"Found 3 problem(s)\nline 
1:30: Unknown column [Date], did you mean [path]?\nline 1:43: 
Unknown column [2019-07-29T08:00:45.000Z]\nline 1:74: Unknown column 
[2019-08- 
29T08:00:45.000Z]"}],"type":"verification_exception","reason":"Found 
3 problem(s)\nline 1:30: Unknown column [Date], did you mean [path]? 
\nline 1:43: Unknown column [2019-07-29T08:00:45.000Z]\nline 1:74: 
Unknown column [2019-08-29T08:00:45.000Z]"},"status":400}
```

I have tried these things

1) I have changed double quotation to single quotation without forward slash.

2)I have changed **"query"** to **\"query\"**

3)I have changed **Date** column to **Date_Created**

But nothing works.So what is the issue and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

It should be work like this

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/_sql?format=json" -H 'Content-Type: 
application/json' -d "{\"query\": \"select * from abusix_1 where Date between 
'2019-07-29T08:00:45.000Z' and '2019-08-29T08:00:45.000Z'\"}"
```